# How to declare 2D integer array in C#?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am at beginner level of programming, and I would like to know how to declare a 2-dimension array in C#. I did look it up on Google but I couldn't find a solution.

Please answer this question at my level.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Two-dimensional array.

```
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

// The same array with dimensions specified.

```
int[,] array2Da = new int[4, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

// A similar array with string elements.

```
string[,] array2Db = new string[3, 2] { { "one", "two" }, { "three", "four" },
                                    { "five", "six" } };
```

// Three-dimensional array.

```
int[, ,] array3D = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                             { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

// The same array with dimensions specified.

```
int[, ,] array3Da = new int[2, 2, 3] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                                   { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this. See details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

```
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

Answer (score 1):

2D integer array

`Declaration`

```
int[,] array = new int[4, 2];
```

`Initialization`

```
int[,] array = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

Complete explanation with example :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i think you have not searched google....

follow below link to see tutorial
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

```
int [,] a = int [3,4] = {  
 {0, 1, 2, 3} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
 {4, 5, 6, 7} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
 {8, 9, 10, 11}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MSDN for Micrsoft technologies, it is well documented http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

It ranked #1 in google search for me when writing: 2d integer array c#

This page might also provide useful information: [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: You are right with the link. I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

The sum2D() Method

```
private double sum2D(double[,] ar)
{
 double sum = 0.0;

 foreach (double d in ar)
      sum += d;

 return sum;
}
```